# C++ function name as parameter

Tags: c++, parameters

almost absolute beginner here. This is the code for an example from the Qt docs:

```
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Counter() { m_value = 0; }

    int value() const { return m_value; }

public slots:
    void setValue(int value);

signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

`value()` is a function?
So is the `value` in the parameters for `setValue(int value)` calling the function `value()` without using the parenthesis and, hence, getting the return value of `value()` to pass to setValue()?

Comment: Coding examples like that make me sad.

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> So is the value in the parameters for `setValue(int value)` calling the function `value()` without using the parenthesis and, hence, getting the return value of `value()` to pass to `setValue()`?

No. The identifier `value` in the function `setValue()` shadows  the member function `value`. Inside `setValue()`, you can refer to both of them but they need different syntax.

```
void setValue(int value)
{
    m_value = value; // This is the argument.
    this->value()    // This calls the member function.
}
```

Comment: Don't know of any other way of posting 'thanks' to all who answered. I am embarrassed that I didn't see that. I remember now that when I first tried learning C++ years ago we never used the same identifier(?) for different things so it kind of threw me.

Answer (score 0):

No. The name of `setValue`s parameter is just an ordinary local variable of type `int`. It is not related in any way to the `Counter::value()` function.

Inside `Counter::setValue` function parameter `value` will *hide* class member function `value()`. This means that inside `Counter::setValue` unqualified name `value` will always refer to the parameter.

You still can work around the hiding and refer to the member function by using a qualified name `Counter::value()` or by  referring to it as `this->value()`.